# UV unwrapping a hollow cylinder sequentially

Tags: uv

I have a "simple" problem. I want to create a hollow cylinder and UV unwrap it so i can texture it later. All i want is that the 200 quads (10 here for example) be uv unwrapped sequentually so when i apply an image as texture it comes out as the image itself on teh cylinder. However, using any kind of UV unwrapping (angle, conformal, smart, cube etc) is sort of randomly assigning the edges onto the UV map. For example the connected 2nd face to first face might be after 3 faces in the UV map. Here i tried the smart UV unwrapping and as u can see it resizes the different faces, makes some horizontal, some vertical.. this would be fine if the ylinder had 10 faces but when it will have 200 faces for smoothness, i cannot manually check how the faces are being UV mapped "randomly".  Last time i managed ot do this using conformal but its not working anymore.   [image: blender issue]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try the cylindrical mapping option?

1. Select your cylinder and go to edit mode.
2. Select all faces.
3. Go to either front <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> or side view <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>.
4. Go to orthographic view mode <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>.
5. <kbd>U</kbd> --> Cylindrical projection.

[image]