# Place stretched texture on outside of hollow cylinder

Tags: texturing, uv

As I am new to Blender this is probably an easy question, but I am kind of stuck.

I created a hollow cylinder (Create -> Cylinder -> No fill -> Add Modifier -> Solidify) and want to apply a texture stretched to the outside of it.

While I first struggled with the texture being applied to every vertice of the cylinder ([this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69267/uv-unwrapping-a-hollow-cylinder-sequentially) fixed that - kind of), I now have the problem that I have horizontal "layers" in the rendering and also that the pattern/texture is applied to the inside of the element and not the outside.

*Update: I fixed this part by using a pattern which has the right side ratio and by setting the "Extension" in Image Mapping to "Extend".*

My final result should stretch across the whole outer surface like the label of a can. I have seen lots of videos regarding this, but they use older versions of Blender, so some settings have changed...

Comment: Could you add some Images to your post that show your render result and/or the cylinder in the viewport? I don't quite understand what you mean by "horizontal layers".

Comment: Your polygon faces are facing the wrong way. In the 3d world they called it the surface normals. So basically you need to tell the model to flip their faces around. Steps are as follows. Select your model hit TAB to enter edit model and hit T to open tool panel. Select the Shading/UVs tabs ... Remember to select all the faces of your model and hit the Recalculate button it should fix the normals >> if not then you may have to flip them visually using the Flip direction button. What went wrong was the solidify modifier, you basically solidify the model in the "wrong" direction, hence flipped.

Comment: Thank you so far. I clicked on my Cylinder in the "Explorer" in the upper right and hit Tab, but clicking on "Recalculate" or "Flip" and Rerendering does not change anything about the side the pattern is applied to. Do I miss something here?