# How to apply an image texture on a cylinder

Tags: materials, image

I've tried googling it, but nothing I do works.

See my screen shot:

[image]

I've applied the image texture, and the pipe has the image on it but its just stretched for most of the pipe.  It's no different when I render it out.  I've tried adding a 'mapping' mode, but that doesn't work.  What confuses me is that the in the materials tab it says 'repeat', so it should be repeating.

How can I get it to cover the pipe?

Comment: You need to define UV coordinates, so that the image is mapped on the surface in a controllable way. By default when you use a texture in a material it will use UV coordinates. The way you connected your current node tree would require you to "unwrap" the mesh to define the UV mapping. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69267/uv-unwrapping-a-hollow-cylinder-sequentially and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXYqr4w6li4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UV map is a 2D representation of a 3D object.

The name UV map is derived from its axis’. In 3D space, x y and z is used to represent the dimensions of width, depth and height respectively. When we go to a 2D plane, instead of using xy, we use uv as shown below.

[image: 3DCoords]
[image: 2DCoords]

If you unfolded a cardboard box and laid it out flat, that is a representation of your cubes surface area.

Blender uses this 2D mesh to allow texturing.  By colouring in the faces of the unwrapped mesh, blender will project that image onto the respective face on your mesh.

[image: 3D to UV]

If you leave blender to unwrap the mesh itself, stretching can occur. This is when a rectangular face is unwrapped into a square face, or vice versa. This most often occurs when your objects geometry is unbalanced.

To fix this, select your object and go into edit mode. Select everything and press control-u and choose smart uv unwrap. Press ok on the pop up window.

In the image viewer, you should now see your mesh presented in 2D.

If the 2D mesh does not look proportionally correct to your object, you will need to apply the scale.

Blender has two ways of storing it’s dimensional size data. One is the each axis’ length which is the true size and the other is the objects dimensions which is used for accurate scaling and uv mapping. If you scale your mesh on one axis or extrude or extend it in any form, the dimensions change on one axis only.

For example; we have a cube 5x5x5 units and dimensions of 1x1x2. When blender tries to unwrap it, it will stretch any face that had an z direction. So your cube will have four sides twice as long as the others. Try it  in blender to gain a better understanding.

[image: Texture Streaching]

Note how the faces on the UV in the image editor look like they are all in the same proportion and on the object they aren't, stretching the texture

To fix this, go to object mode and select your item. Go to object->apply->scale. Fixed. You may need to go through the uv unwrapping process again.

Here is the quad with correct UV unwrapping:

[image: Correct UV Unwrap]

Quick tip:

If you have multiple objects that require uv unwrapping, do it to one object then select the rest. Set the active object to the object you just UV unwrapped and hit control L. Chose object data.

Tada. Magic.

Good luck with your project and I hope I helped,

BFB

Comment: Thank you for your help, although ctrl +u doesn't seem to do anything in edit mode?

Comment: Apologies. It was just u. No pun intended :D

Comment: That worked! At the moment I don't understand why, but thank you.

Comment: If you give me until tomorrow, I can update my answer with images to help as I am messaging from my phone :/

Comment: Yay that would be lovely thank you!

Comment: So `go into edit mode. Select everything and press control-u` is still wrong?  And I only see `Smart UV Project`

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

1. Have you UV unwrapped the mesh?
2. Have you applied the scale in object mode? If this is your problem you may need to re unwrap your object once applied.
3. Can you post an image of your nodes with the mapping nodes if the two above don’t work.

Good luck with your project and I hope I helped,

BFB

Comment: I'm not sure which mode I added the texture in does that matter?and sorry I don't under stand point 1 at all 

Comment: To apply the object's scale go to Object mode (hit Ctrl+Tab and choose Object mode on the left. Then hit Ctrl+A and choose Scale to apply the object's scale. Then the scale of the object will be 1 in X, Y and Z.

Comment: So do you want me to explain what a UV map is and why it is important or are you wondering why I included it?

Comment: @BigfootBlondy you can edit your answers using the [edit] link. No need to add aditional answers unless you are proposing two completely different workflows.